# Finding and display custom user variables

Tags: users, debugging

I have create a series of user fields. Some of these fields reference taxonomy terms, require a mobile number or are just basic text fields. I used the below to print one of the fields (the number field) inside my page.tpl.php.

```
global $user;
$user = user_load($user->uid); // Make sure the user object is fully loaded
$number = $user->field_phone_number['und'][0]['value'];

if (isset($number) && !empty($number)) :
print 'Cell: ' . $number;
endif;
```

My question is how would I go about finding the information I need to print the other fields? The potion that reads `['und'][0]['value'];` in particularly is where i'm stuck. I have used devel before to find this information for node variables but I cant find similar information for custom user variables.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to have [Xdebug](https://xdebug.org/) installed so that you can add breakpoints, pause execution and inspect surrounding variables. Alternatively, you can use [Kint](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) to print out variables.

Comment: Hi my site is built on Drupal 7 and it seems kint only ships with D8 Devel.